# Github page's not showing enumeration properly

Tags: html, markdown, github-pages

I'm working on my portfolio using a Github Page: https://diegoguisasola.github.io/

I have the following problem:

This is a link to my README.md: https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/DiegoGuisasola.github.io/blob/main/README.md

As you can see, in the section called Data Science I have 2 projects. I'm enumerating them as follows:

1- [EDA y algoritmos de ML para la predicción de precios de propiedades inmobiliarias (Spanish)]

2- [Pokemon EDA (English)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon)

But when I go the my portfolio page, it is shown as follows:

1- [EDA y algoritmos de ML para la predicción de precios de propiedades inmobiliarias (Spanish)]

1- [Pokemon EDA (English)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon)

This is my html code:

```
## Data Science projects
1. [EDA y algoritmos de ML para la predicción de precios de propiedades inmobiliarias (Spanish)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/data-science/tree/main/properati/argentina)

<p align="center">
  <img src="/images/cantidad_por_regiones.png" alt="drawing" width="500"/>
</p>

#### Problema
Se propone crear un modelo de Machine Learning que, dadas ciertas características de la propiedad, prediga el precio de venta.

1. Se realiza un EDA.
2. Se implementan 3 modelos de ML y se mide cuál es el mejor: Regresión lineal, DecisionTreeRegressor y KNN.

*Estado: En desarrollo*


2. [Pokemon EDA (English)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon)

Description: Exploratory Data Analysis of all Pokemon. Fast approach using sweetviz.

<p align="center">
  <img src="/images/pokemon.jpeg" alt="drawing" width="500"/>
</p>

The report can be seeing in [this link](https://raw.githack.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon/main/analyze.html).
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT 1:
I've done what @Waylan suggests without success.

[image: Indent the child block of your list items.]

EDIT 2: @Waylan suggestions works when using 2 tabs instead of only one.

Comment: Both current and expected outputs are the same thing?

Comment: No. current is:
1. item
1. item
Expected is:
1. item
2. item

Comment: Well, it shows up as 1. item 2. item for me.

Comment: You might be looking at the wrong site. This is the one where the error is shown: https://diegoguisasola.github.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent the child block of your list items.

You can not have any non-list item blocks between list items. However, you can have child blocks of a list item. All child blocks must be indented at least one level.

```
## Data Science projects
1. [EDA y algoritmos de ML para la predicción de precios de propiedades inmobiliarias (Spanish)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/data-science/tree/main/properati/argentina)

    <p align="center">
      <img src="/images/cantidad_por_regiones.png" alt="drawing" width="500"/>
    </p>

    #### Problema
    Se propone crear un modelo de Machine Learning que, dadas ciertas características de la propiedad, prediga el precio de venta.

    1. Se realiza un EDA.
    2. Se implementan 3 modelos de ML y se mide cuál es el mejor: Regresión lineal, DecisionTreeRegressor y KNN.

    *Estado: En desarrollo*


2. [Pokemon EDA (English)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon)

    Description: Exploratory Data Analysis of all Pokemon. Fast approach using sweetviz.

    <p align="center">
      <img src="/images/pokemon.jpeg" alt="drawing" width="500"/>
    </p>

    The report can be seeing in [this link](https://raw.githack.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon/main/analyze.html).
```

The above will render as:

> ### Data Science projects
>
> 1. [EDA y algoritmos de ML para la predicción de precios de propiedades inmobiliarias
>    (Spanish)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/data-science/tree/main/properati/argentina)
>
>    Problema
>
>    Se propone crear un modelo de Machine Learning que, dadas ciertas características de la propiedad, prediga el precio de venta.
>
>    1. Se realiza un EDA.
>    2. Se implementan 3 modelos de ML y se mide cuál es el mejor: Regresión lineal, DecisionTreeRegressor y KNN.
>
>    *Estado: En desarrollo*
> 2. [Pokemon EDA (English)](https://github.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon)
>
>    Description: Exploratory Data Analysis of all Pokemon. Fast approach using sweetviz.
>
>    The report can be seeing in [this link](https://raw.githack.com/DiegoGuisasola/pokemon/main/analyze.html).

Comment: I've updated the questions using your suggestion. No success yet.
Edit. I 'TAB' twice and it worked! Thanks!